Random intercepts model question
I'm working on a paper right now examining the association between undergraduate school cost of attendance and the racial demographics of an institution's student body. My analysis includes separate models for all schools; HBCUs; Ivy Leagues; and non-Ivy League/non-Historically Black College. Currently, I am using a two way fixed effects with controls for county cost-of-living and institutional test scores. In passing, one of my advisors suggested considering a mixed effects or random effects model. He just went on vacation and is unreachable. What would be the rational for using random or mixed effects?

Please spell out your acronyms. I know what a HBCU is, but not everyone will. I don't recognize the acronym TWFE.

I think the rationale would be that you have (or seem to have) both institution level variables and county level variables (and maybe also student level).
